# is there any way to cancel a dart Future?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

In a Dart UI, I have a button `submit` to launch a long async request. The `submit` handler returns a Future. Next, the button `submit` is replaced by a button `cancel` to allow the cancellation of the whole operation. In the `cancel` handler, I would like to cancel the long operation. How can I cancel the Future returned by the submit handler? I found no method to do that.

Comment: The answers are fine. Just for context: You cannot cancel a *future*. Futures are not operations, they are objects representing the *result* of an operation. There is no built-in way to tell a future to tell the underlying operation to stop. That's why all the solutions here are to use something other than a `Future`. That's also why futures in Dart can be *shared*. If anyone could cancel a future for everybody else, you'd have to be much more careful how you share futures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to cancel a Future. But there is a way to cancel a Stream subscription, and maybe that can help you.

Calling `onSubmit` on a button returns a `StreamSubscription` object. You can explicitly store that object and then call `cancel()` on it to cancel the stream subscription:

```dart
StreamSubscription subscription = someDOMElement.onSubmit.listen((data) {

   // you code here

   if (someCondition == true) {
     subscription.cancel();
   }
});
```

Later, as a response to some user action, perhaps, you can cancel the subscription:

Comment: I followed your idea. It worked well. The matter was the following. A DAO layer returned 1000 random numbers, each random number being generated by a remote server via 1000 HTTP requests. The DAO layer returned a response including 2 lists :  a list of 1000 Future<int> and a list of 1000 StreamSubscription linked to the 1000 HTTP requests. I used the futures to show the random numbers in a UI and the StreamSubscriptions to cancel the HTTP requests.  Thank you !

Comment: Also, do you really need a 1000 HTTP requests? Any reason you cannot just generate a 1000 random numbers using Math.Random? Or have just a single HTTP request that gets you all the numbers?

Comment: I just wanted to test the cancellation of a list of Future. That's the way I found to do this test. Yes I accept the answer.

Answer (score 131):

You can use [CancelableOperation](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html) or [CancelableCompleter](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableCompleter-class.html) to cancel a future. See below the 2 versions:

#### Solution 1: `CancelableOperation` (included in a test so you can try it yourself):

- #### cancel a future

```
test("CancelableOperation with future", () async {

  var cancellableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
    Future.value('future result'),
    onCancel: () => {debugPrint('onCancel')},
  );

// cancellableOperation.cancel();  // uncomment this to test cancellation

  cancellableOperation.value.then((value) => {
    debugPrint('then: $value'),
  });
  cancellableOperation.value.whenComplete(() => {
    debugPrint('onDone'),
  });
});
```

- #### cancel a stream

```
test("CancelableOperation with stream", () async {

  var cancellableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
    Future.value('future result'),
    onCancel: () => {debugPrint('onCancel')},
  );

  //  cancellableOperation.cancel();  // uncomment this to test cancellation

  cancellableOperation.asStream().listen(
        (value) => { debugPrint('value: $value') },
    onDone: () => { debugPrint('onDone') },
  );
});
```

Both above tests will output:

```
then: future result
onDone
```

Now if we uncomment the `cancellableOperation.cancel();` then both above tests will output:

```
onCancel
```

#### Solution 2: `CancelableCompleter` (if you need more control)

```
test("CancelableCompleter is cancelled", () async {

  CancelableCompleter completer = CancelableCompleter(onCancel: () {
    print('onCancel');
  });

  // completer.operation.cancel();  // uncomment this to test cancellation

  completer.complete(Future.value('future result'));
  print('isCanceled: ${completer.isCanceled}');
  print('isCompleted: ${completer.isCompleted}');
  completer.operation.value.then((value) => {
    print('then: $value'),
  });
  completer.operation.value.whenComplete(() => {
    print('onDone'),
  });
});
```

Output:

```
isCanceled: false
isCompleted: true
then: future result
onDone
```

Now if we uncomment the `cancellableOperation.cancel();` we get output:

```
onCancel
isCanceled: true
isCompleted: true
```

Be aware that if you use `await cancellableOperation.value` or `await completer.operation` then the future will never return a result and it will await indefinitely if the operation was cancelled. This is because `await cancellableOperation.value` is the same as writing `cancellableOperation.value.then(...)` but `then()` will never be called if the operation was cancelled.

#### Remember to add [async](https://pub.dev/packages/async) Dart package.

[Code gist](https://gist.github.com/vladostaci/debbde639489289f483be74ae1bdc1e4)

Comment: Kudos for using standard dart libraries, instead of inventing your own wheel.

Comment: That's not a standard dart lib though. That's an external dependency.

Comment: good point about async. That's super confusing because there is also a native package called async

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with delayed futures. Those are `Timer` based and the internal timer reference isn't saved so there is no way to prevent execution of the callback once it has begun.

Comment: this answer is misleading. these classes don't cancel the future itself, rather creat wrappers you can use to imitate the cancellation behavior

Comment: It does not actually cancel the future. For example, this method is printed until the end.
```
Future<int> tenCounter() async {
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 10){
      print('i: $i');
      i++;
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    }

    return i;
  }
```

Answer (score 49):

### How to cancel `Future.delayed`

A simple way is to use `Timer` instead :)

```dart
Timer _timer;

void _schedule() {
  _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () { 
    print('Do something after delay');
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: But you can't `await` on `Timer` :(

Comment: How do you call cancel _timer upon a gesturedetector ontap?

Comment: @Texv `_timer?.cancel();`

Comment: @AndreyGordeev nevermind I had something else in mind. _timer?.cancel() cancels the  function from operating after duration timer is over. Instead I wanted to cancel the duration (jump to 0 seconds) to perform the function quicker

Comment: @iDecode You can have the `Timer` complete a `Completer`, and callers can `await` the `Completer`'s `Future`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Oh my goodness, thank you so much sir for sharing that. You always prove (in one way or the other), you're the Best!!!

Comment: Nice way to solve the issue. It's not exactly canceling future but it does what I need for the case

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion @jamesdlin! I have implemented it and it works perfectly. You can see it in my answer (`CancelableCompleter`).

Comment: There is a simple solution that is cancelable like a Timer AND awaitable like a Future, with no added dependency. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303616/2083587

Comment: Shouldn't super.dispose() be after disposing everything else?!

Comment: @Unknown you're right. Fixed.

Comment: The question clearly states how to cancel a [Future]. Why are you answering for [Future.delayed] specifically? And not even involving [Future] but [Timer] class instead. Completely mis-directioned.

Answer (score 9):

One way I accomplished to 'cancel' a scheduled execution was using a `Timer`. In this case I was actually postponing it. :)

```
Timer _runJustOnceAtTheEnd;

void runMultipleTimes() {
  _runJustOnceAtTheEnd?.cancel();
  _runJustOnceAtTheEnd = null;

  // do your processing

  _runJustOnceAtTheEnd = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), onceAtTheEndOfTheBatch);
}

void onceAtTheEndOfTheBatch() {
  print("just once at the end of a batch!");
}


runMultipleTimes();
runMultipleTimes();
runMultipleTimes();
runMultipleTimes();

// will print 'just once at the end of a batch' one second after last execution
```

The `runMultipleTimes()` method will be called multiple times in sequence, but only after 1 second of a batch the `onceAtTheEndOfTheBatch` will be executed.

Comment: The OP asked about canceling a Future, not execution.

Answer (score 9):

For those, who are trying to achieve this in Flutter, here is the simple example for the same.

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final CancelableCompleter<bool> _completer = CancelableCompleter(onCancel: () => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Future")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Submit"),
            onPressed: () async {
              // it is true only if the future got completed
              bool _isFutureCompleted = await _submit();
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(child: Text("Cancel"), onPressed: _cancel),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _submit() async {
    _completer.complete(Future.value(_solve()));
    return _completer.operation.value;
  }

  // This is just a simple method that will finish the future in 5 seconds
  Future<bool> _solve() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => true);
  }

  void _cancel() async {
    var value = await _completer.operation.cancel();
    // if we stopped the future, we get false
    assert(value == false);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is great, but completer only can run once. so you can't call _submit() multiple times. Any solution for handling that thing?

Answer (score 6):

my 2 cents worth...

```
class CancelableFuture {
  bool cancelled = false;
  CancelableFuture(Duration duration, void Function() callback) {
    Future<void>.delayed(duration, () {
      if (!cancelled) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }

  void cancel() {
    cancelled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at CancelableOperation in the accepted answer.

Comment: @JonScalet I don't think `CancelableOperation` prevents the future callback from executing, whereas the answer does. Try cancelling a `Future.delayed(...)` and it will still execute --- `CancelableOperation.fromFuture(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print("Finished 1")), onCancel: () => print("Cancelled"),).cancel()`

Comment: @geg You're right, it doesn't actually cancel the computation/execution of the Future.

Comment: Nice... but it's not a Future as the name suggests, so it can't be awaited. Sad, because being able to await the `Future` is one of the main reasons I would use a `Future` over a `Timer`.

Comment: For a cancelable delayed future that can be awaited take a look at my answer (`CancelableCompleter`)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [CancelableOperation](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html) in the [async package](https://pub.dev/packages/async) on pub.dev that you can use to do this now. This package is not to be confused with the built in dart core library `dart:async`, which doesn't have this class.

Answer (score 2):

The following code helps to design the future function that timeouts and can be canceled manually.

```
import 'dart:async';

class API {
  Completer<bool> _completer;
  Timer _timer;

  // This function returns 'true' only if timeout >= 5 and
  // when cancelOperation() function is not called after this function call.
  //
  // Returns false otherwise
  Future<bool> apiFunctionWithTimeout() async {
    _completer = Completer<bool>();
    // timeout > time taken to complete _timeConsumingOperation() (5 seconds)
    const timeout = 6;

    // timeout < time taken to complete _timeConsumingOperation() (5 seconds)
    // const timeout = 4;

    _timeConsumingOperation().then((response) {
      if (_completer.isCompleted == false) {
        _timer?.cancel();
        _completer.complete(response);
      }
    });

    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: timeout), () {
      if (_completer.isCompleted == false) {
        _completer.complete(false);
      }
    });

    return _completer.future;
  }

  void cancelOperation() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    if (_completer.isCompleted == false) {
      _completer.complete(false);
    }
  }

  // this can be an HTTP call.
  Future<bool> _timeConsumingOperation() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => true);
  }
}

void main() async {
  API api = API();
  api.apiFunctionWithTimeout().then((response) {
    // prints 'true' if the function is not timed out or canceled, otherwise it prints false
    print(response);
  });
  // manual cancellation. Uncomment the below line to cancel the operation.
  //api.cancelOperation();
}
```

The return type can be changed from `bool` to your own data type. `Completer` object also should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the future's task from 'do something' to 'do something unless it has been cancelled'. An obvious way to implement this would be to set a boolean flag and check it in the future's closure before embarking on processing, and perhaps at several points during the processing.

Also, this seems to be a bit of a hack, but setting the future's timeout to zero would appear to effectively cancel the future.

Comment: It seems setting the future's timeout to zero does not cancel the future.

Below are code and outputs that prove this.

    `Future f = new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2), () => print('2 secs passed'));
    f.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 0), onTimeout: () { print ('timed out'); });`

prints

    `timed out
    2 secs passed`
. Catching the raised timeout with catchError, or providing the onTimeout parameter does not make a difference. The future is always ran.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's a solution to cancel an awaitable delayed future

This solution is like **an awaitable `Timer`** or a **cancelable `Future.delayed`**: it's cancelable like a `Timer` AND awaitable like a `Future`.

It's base on a very simple class, `CancelableCompleter`, here's a demo:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {  
  print('start');
  
  // Create a completer that completes after 2 seconds…
  final completer = CancelableCompleter.auto(Duration(seconds: 2));
  
  // … but schedule the cancelation after 1 second
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), completer.cancel);
  
  // We want to await the result
  final result = await completer.future;

  print(result ? 'completed' : 'canceled');
  print('done');
  // OUTPUT:
  //  start
  //  canceled
  //  done
}
```

Now the code of the class:

```dart
class CancelableCompleter {
  CancelableCompleter.auto(Duration delay) : _completer = Completer() {
    _timer = Timer(delay, _complete);
  }

  final Completer<bool> _completer;
  late final Timer? _timer;

  bool _isCompleted = false;
  bool _isCanceled = false;

  Future<bool> get future => _completer.future;

  void cancel() {
    if (!_isCompleted && !_isCanceled) {
      _timer?.cancel();
      _isCanceled = true;
      _completer.complete(false);
    }
  }

  void _complete() {
    if (!_isCompleted && !_isCanceled) {
      _isCompleted = true;
      _completer.complete(true);
    }
  }
}
```

A running example with a more complete class is available in [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=392d4b4e03e02699cde81f885f8281e9&null_safety=true).

Answer (score 0):

A little class to unregister callbacks from future. This class will not prevent from execution, but can help when you need to switch to another future with the same type. Unfortunately I didn't test it, but:

```
class CancelableFuture<T> {
  Function(Object) onErrorCallback;
  Function(T) onSuccessCallback;
  bool _wasCancelled = false;

  CancelableFuture(Future<T> future,
      {this.onSuccessCallback, this.onErrorCallback}) {
    assert(onSuccessCallback != null || onErrorCallback != null);
    future.then((value) {
      if (!_wasCancelled && onSuccessCallback != null) {
        onSuccessCallback(value);
      }
    }, onError: (e) {
      if (!_wasCancelled && onErrorCallback != null) {
        onErrorCallback(e);
      }
    });
  }

  cancel() {
    _wasCancelled = true;
  }
}
```

And here is example of usage. P.S. I use provider in my project:

```
_fetchPlannedLists() async {
    if (_plannedListsResponse?.status != Status.LOADING) {
      _plannedListsResponse = ApiResponse.loading();
      notifyListeners();
    }

    _plannedListCancellable?.cancel();

    _plannedListCancellable = CancelableFuture<List<PlannedList>>(
        _plannedListRepository.fetchPlannedLists(),
        onSuccessCallback: (plannedLists) {
      _plannedListsResponse = ApiResponse.completed(plannedLists);
      notifyListeners();
    }, onErrorCallback: (e) {
      print('Planned list provider error: $e');
      _plannedListsResponse = ApiResponse.error(e);
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

You could use it in situations, when language changed, and request was made, you don't care about previous response and making another request!
In addition, I really was wondered that this feature didn't come from the box.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use timeout() method**

Create a dummy future:

```
Future<String?> _myFuture() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    return 'Future completed';
}
```

Setting a timeout of 3 seconds to stop early from 10sec:

```
_myFuture().timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      onTimeout: () =>
          'The process took too much time to finish. Please try again later',
);
```

and thats it you cancel your FUTURE.

Comment: This does not Cancel the future. it "Stop[s] waiting for this future after [timeLimit] has passed." The async function will still run, we are just no longer waiting for it.

Answer (score -1):

there is no way unfortunately, take a look:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:async/async.dart';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final object = SomeTimer();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  object.dispose();
  print('finish program');
}

class SomeTimer {
  SomeTimer() {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    completer
        .complete(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () => someState = 1));
    print('before wait');
    await completer.operation.valueOrCancellation();
    print('after wait');
    if (completer.isCanceled) {
      print('isCanceled');
      return;
    }
    print('timer');
    timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), (() => print('finish timer')));
  }

  Timer? timer;
  int _someState = 0;
  set someState(int value) {
    print('someState set to $value');
    _someState = value;
  }

  CancelableCompleter completer = CancelableCompleter(onCancel: () {
    print('onCancel');
  });

  void dispose() {
    completer.operation.cancel();
    timer?.cancel();
  }
}
```

after ten seconds you will see `someState set to 1` no matter what