# How to delete a Dart future when it's no longer needed

Tags: dart, dart-async

This is related to [is there any way to cancel a dart Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552757/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dart-future)

In my case, there are no HTTP, just expensive calculations.  I have a table/list which I scroll through. As the elements become visible, I generate futures to show the calculation results. But if I (the end user) scroll quickly, some results will have "scrolled out of view" and will no longer required. This could be a large number, and would seriously delay the return of futures (results) that are to be usefully :-) displayed in currently visible elements. Can something be done about that?
 cheers, Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set a flag which indicates to the delayed code (run from futures) that the result isn't needed anymore.
When the delayed code is called it just returns.

```dart
library cancel_future;

import 'dart:async' show Future, Timer;
import 'dart:math' show Random;

typedef void TaskFunction(Task task);

// Container for a task
class Task {
  // an assigned task id
  final id;
  // data to process
  int data;
  // Indicate to the task function, that it should stop processing
  bool isCanceled = false;
  // The task function must set this flat to true when all work is done.
  bool isFinished = false;
  // The task function which processed the data and sets the result.
  TaskFunction fn;
  // The result set by the task function when it finished processing.
  int result;

  Task(this.id, this.data, this.fn);

  // Start processing the task.
  void execute() => fn(this);
}

final rnd = new Random();

void main(List<String> args) {

  // create tasks
  final tasks = new List<Task>.from(generate());

  // start all tasks
  tasks.forEach((t) => t.execute());

  // after random delay cancel all unfinished tasks
  new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: rnd.nextInt(10)), () {
    tasks.forEach((t) {
      if (!t.isFinished) {
        t.isCanceled = true;
      }
    });
  }).then((_) {
    // check results
    int done = 0;
    int canceled = 0;
    tasks.forEach((t) {
      print(
          'Task id: ${t.id}; isCanceled: ${t.isCanceled}; isFinished: ${t.isFinished}; data: ${t.data}; result: ${t.result}');
      if (t.isFinished) {
        done++;
      }
      if (t.isCanceled) {
        canceled++;
      }
    });

    print('Canceled: $canceled.');
    print('Done: $done.');
  });
}

// geneator for job 100 jobs
Iterable<Task> generate() sync* {
  int i = 0;

  while (i++ < 100) {
    yield new Task(i, rnd.nextInt(100), calc);
  }
}

// job function
void calc(Task t) {
  // do a bit of work every 100ms to simulate longer processing
  new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
    var result = 0;
    // check if jost was canceled and stop processing in case it was.
    if (t.isCanceled) {
      timer.cancel();
      return;
    }
    // while not finished do a chunk of work
    if (result < t.data) {
      result++;
    } else {
      // finished - clean up and store result
      t.isFinished = true;
      t.result = result;
      timer.cancel();
    }
  });
}
```