# How to catch errors thrown in timer function calls?

Tags: dart

I have code similar to:

```
  timer = new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () => (throw new TimeoutException('Callback not invoked!')));

  while (timer.isActive){
    await new  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () => "1");
  }
  print('this should not be reached if the exception is raised');
```

elsewhere I have an async callback which calls:

```
timer.cancel();
```

In the case where the callback is invoked it works fine because the callback cancels the timer.

However, I'm not really sure how to actually catch the `TimeoutException` in this case if it is not canceled, because it seems the exception is raised in a different scope than my main function. This means program execution continues even though

Is there a way to do some sort of try/catch or somehow handle the above timeout exception? Or a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Using dart 1.19.1.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `Timer`? What about using `Future.delayed().timeout...`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if that is a better option I'm more than willing to use it. I was originally using the timer because I can actually track how long the entire callback takes but wasn't able to get that working with a future based operation.

Answer (score 8):

You get different behavior depending on whether the timeout is `500ms` or `1500ms`:

```
   final timer = new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), 
         () => (throw new Exception('Callback not invoked!')))
     .timeout(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
   try {
     await timer;
   } on TimeoutException catch(e) {
     print('this should not be reached if the exception is raised');
   } on Exception catch(e) {
     print('exception: $e');
   }
```

[**DartPad**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9a4be60fd520a1d3d85d319e95a8ac97)

Comment: How can I cancel the timer future in my other callback? Previously I could just `timer.cancel()` which worked, but I'm not clear how to resolve the future here prior to the timeout occurring from another callback?

Comment: I see. Didn't think of that. I don't think there is a way to cancel a `Future`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552757/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dart-future, https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1806