# how can i cancel Future.delayed function calling

Tags: dart, flutter

how can i cancel Future.delayed

i am using Future.delayed for some task, but if i want to cancel this delayed task, so is their any method or any other things to use.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10),(){
  setState(() {
    //some method calling
  });
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15968

Comment: found the answer here https://dart.academy/how_cancel_future/

Comment: you can use a `Timer`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657685/796963)

Answer (score 2):

what about declare a bool value

```
bool _executeFuture=true;
```

then

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10),(){
if(_executeFuture){
  setState(() {
    //some method calling
  });
}
});
```

Now whenever you want to cancel Future just use

```
_executeFuture=false;
```

Also,  You can use CancelableOperation from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async

Comment: Is this really cancelling the future or just not executing the code within?  I feel like that is a pretty significant difference.

Comment: It's just preventing the future code to be executed. Future will anyway run the code. As calling Future is an asynchronous and we do not get any reference for the called function  so, the option remains just to prevent the code from being executed if it is no longer required. You can use You can use CancelableOperation from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async if needed