# Wait for stream inside a Future: Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if the Firebase DB is connected or not, so I have to use a Future to return a boolean

Have a check at my code..

```
@override
Future<bool> isAvailable() async {
 bool ret = false;
 await firebaseInstance.reference().child('.info/connected').onValue.listen((event) {
  ret =  event.snapshot.value;
});

return ret;
}
```

the firebaseInstace.reference is a StreamSubscription type and does not wait for the future to return me a result.

please help.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of awaiting the end of the stream subscription (it never ends), just take the `first` value:

```dart
@override
Future<bool> isAvailable() => firebaseInstance.reference().child('.info/connected').onValue.first;
```

Comment: You saved me! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to know the current value, use [`once().then`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) instead of `onValue.listen`

```
@override
Future<bool> isAvailable() async {
  var snapshot = await firebaseInstance.reference().child('.info/connected').once();
  return snapshot.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the StreamSubcription in a variable

```
StreamSubscription subscription = someDOMElement.onSubmit.listen((data) {

   // you code here

   if (someCondition == true) {
     subscription.cancel();
   }
```

});

More can be found here [is there any way to cancel a dart Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552757/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dart-future)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
@override
  Future<bool> isAvailable() async {
    bool ret = false;
    Stream<Event> events =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('.info/connected').onValue;
    await for (var value in events) {
      ret = value.snapshot.value;
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

`onValue` returns a `Stream<Event>` and then you can use `await for` to iterate inside the Stream and get the data, and then it will return.