# How to cancel or psuedo cancel an http request? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a search bar, when characters are entered it sends a request to a BLoC, which then requests data from a Future.

Here is the BLoC

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:stockrails/models/semantics/error-type-model.dart';
import 'package:stockrails/models/user-interface/search-query-model.dart';
import 'package:stockrails/services/apis/stock-data.dart';
import 'package:stockrails/shared/constants/messages.dart';

part 'search_event.dart';
part 'search_state.dart';

class SearchBloc extends Bloc<SearchEvent, SearchState> {
  SearchBloc() : super(SearchInitial());

  // Connection to api service
  StockData _data = StockData();

  @override
  Stream<SearchState> mapEventToState(
    SearchEvent event,
  ) async* {
    // : Initial search state - no text has been entered, no loading
    if (event is SearchIntializeEvent) {
      yield SearchInitial();
    }
    // : Querying search state - text is being entered, loading next
    if (event is SearchQueryingEvent) {
      // Yields call
      yield* _mapAPICallToEvent(event.query);
    }
  }

  // + ----------- Functions -------------

  Stream<SearchState> _mapAPICallToEvent(String query) async* {
    // : Yield loading screen based on prior state
    if (state is SearchErrorState)
      yield SearchErrorLoadingState();
    else
      yield SearchLoadingState(query: query);

    // : Attempts to call method
    List<SearchQueryModel> _result;

    try {
      _result = await _data.searchQuery(query);
    } on TimeoutException {
      _result = null;
    } catch (err) {
      _result = [];
    }

    // : If it can't then it defaults to using the unknownErrorMessage
    if (_result == null)
      yield SearchErrorState(errorMessage: Messages.unknownErrorMessage, errorType: ErrorType.errorTypes[0]);

    // : Else if there's no content in the response
    else if (_result.length == 0)
      yield SearchErrorState(errorMessage: query, errorType: ErrorType.errorTypes[1]);

    // : If there's no errors return loaded!
    else {
      yield SearchLoadedState(searchQueryModelList: _result, query: query);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the Future that grabs data

```
  // Grabs data from endpoint and returns or errors
  // If it times out it will throw a TimeoutException
  Future _dataFetch(String url, String query, String token) async {
    try {
      // Build out auth header
      final authHeader = 'Bearer $token';

      final response = await http
          .get(url, headers: <String, String>{
            'query': query,
            'authorization': authHeader,
          })
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10))
          .catchError((error) {
            throw error;
          });

      // Makes sure response is okay
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return json.decode(response.body);
      }

      // If status code is unknown, prints an error
      else {
        throw Exception(Messages.unknownErrorMessage);
      }
    } on TimeoutException catch (error) {
      throw error;
    } on SocketException catch (error) {
      throw error;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

---

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out a solution to make the BLoC `await` for the Future but also to allow `SearchInitializeEvent` to cancel any requests being made.

Because what's happening is on a bad network, the request is trying to go through no matter what and won't stop until it gets a response.

I know you can't cancel Futures, I tried both `CancelableOperation` and `CancelableCompletion` or whatever it's called.

I'm guessing I have to set up my Future as a Stream instead so I can close it. I'm open to any suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can cancel http requests with [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Comment: I tried using Dio but I must've done it wrong. Whenever I'd cancel it the request seemed to keep trying to go through. As well, I found I had to re-define the `Dio()` object whenever I cancelled it because it sort of closed the object from making any further requests

Comment: I agree that there will be no trick to cancel a `Future`, but there is a way to cancel a StreamSubscription. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552757/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dart-future) might help you with how it could be implemented. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 3):

There's a limitation in dart for breaking Streams. It's something that can't be done outside the "loop". This is issue was discussed in detail here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42717

https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1472

You may want to look into this from a different perspective, like overriding the changes made by the recent request. Or if the request results are something that's displayed on screen, then consider not displaying the results instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the client.close() to abort the connection :

```
var client = http.Client();
var uri = Uri.https(host, url, params);
var request = http.Request("get", uri);
http.StreamedResponse response = await client.send(request);

if (condition) //if user needs to abort the request
    client.close();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to stop the currently running requests

Comment: No
you need to make the requests through this approach
and when you need to cancel all request, all you need is to call client.close() 
this because all requests belongs to the specific client