# How to deal with the life cycle of flutter Future and StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

I used a **Future** in the **StatefulWidget**, and the **Future** can still run `then` after the **StatefulWidget** `dispose`. When I need to change the **StatefulWidget** in `then`, it is not safe.

My ideal situation should be that the **StatefulWidget** where the **Future** is located is cancelled after dispose. But I found that there is no way to cancel the **Future**. It has only three states: `not completed`, `completed with value`, and `completed with error`.

Then I found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552757/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dart-future) to cancel the **Future**, but it is still not perfect, I have to use **Stream** or **CancelableOperation**.

Is there a better way to handle the life cycle of **StatefulWidget** and **Future**?

Comment: see how `FutureBuilder` checks if the `Future` can be used:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c19845a8c3/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L628

Comment: @pskink Thanks, although I did not use FutureBuilder, I still need to learn

Comment: so do the same thing in your code, where you are calling `Future.then` method

Comment: @pskink I finally understood that `FutureBuilder` uses `_activeCallbackIdentity `to control whether the then needs to be executed, usually there is no problem. But I often use `await`, if I use it like this, I lose `await`, and I always have to couple the `Future` and `the widget`. I read the cancel program of [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) and it solved my problem. I only need to pass in a `CancelToken` for each `Future` method that needs to be cancelled, which can solve the cancellation and continue to use `await`.