# Update widget every 5 seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I need to do the widget with Flutter like "N users watch on it now", where N comes from the backend, and I need to update it every 5 seconds if the widget is visible.

I tried a few approaches with `Future.delayed` and `Timer` like this ones:

```
            _timer = Timer(
              const Duration(seconds: 5),
              () {
                if (isCounterVisible) {
                  // load data 
                }
              },
            );

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer!.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    }
  }
```

But facing an issue that requests still sending after I go away from this screen, and unit tests failed for the reason `A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed`

Also, I have problems with determining is widget visible or not. I used library `visibility_detector` but seems it does not work with modal windows - the listener does not trigger when the modal window showed.

Comment: How do you go away from this screen?

Comment: Also instead `Timer()`, use Timer.periodic(): `_timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {});`

Comment: @stacktrace2234 I could go back by Navigator.pop(context); and next by Navigator.push(), and show modal window.

Answer (score 3):

`Timer.periodic` will do the job, Also you can use [cancelable future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17552757/10157127). You are missing  `super.dispose();`.

```dart
Timer? timer;

void initTimer() {
  if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) return;

  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
    //job
    setState(() {});
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Now use `initTimer()` to start woker.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RiverPod StreamProvider.autoDispose wrapped around a Timer.periodic to wake up a Consumer Widget at regular intervals.  It will automatically go away when no longer referenced.