How to cancel local file copying (Flutter iOS)
In my application user can copy local file:

user clicks button "copy file".
file copying starts.
user clicks button "cancel copying file" (before file copy done).

I can use CancelableOperation to cancel Future (File.copy), but in this case copy of file is creating even if user canceled the Future.
So I have to delete it myself.
Is it possible to cancel file copying without deleting a copy of file?
This is code:
import 'package:async/async.dart';
...
CancelableOperation? fileCopyingOperation;
...
// user clicks "copy file"
fileCopyingOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
  File(filePath).copy(filePathNew),
  onCancel: () {},
);
...
// user clicks "cancel copying file"
fileCopyingOperation?.cancel();


I guess you meant to ask if the file could be automatically deleted when the copy is cancelled? If so, it seems logical that you have to delete it by yourself, and could just put something like if (file exists) delete it in the onCancel callback, don't you?

@L10.be yes, I have done something like that. But I delete file after copying completes (but not inside onCancel).

I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve... From what I understand, user can cancel a copy while it's copying, and you want the file created to be deleted automatically? File("filePath").copy("newPath") is not aware of your cancelation, so of course it won't handle the deletion of the file. What is the problem about deleting it by yourself in the onCancel callback? If your problem is onCancel doesn't trigger the deletion, perhaps should you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552757/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dart-future?rq=3

@L10.be yes, I think CancelableCompleter is what I need
